# Cassandra-Java-driver : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Invalid type, column is a list but class java.lang.String provided

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

I have a User Defined Type in Cassandra which I created using following syntax in CQLSH :

```
CREATE TYPE order_items (
    qty int,
    name text,
    milk_type text,
    size text,
    price decimal
);
```

Now in my table, I am storing a list of the type "order_items" so I can store multiple items for one object.

Something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE order (
     order_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
     amount decimal,
     location text,
     items list<frozen<order_items>>,
     status text,
     message text
);
```

If I want to store a record using CQLSH, I can do so with the following syntax,

```
INSERT INTO order (order_id,amount,location,items,status,message) VALUES 
(e7ae5cf3-d358-4d99-b900-85902fda9bb0, 5, 'San Jose',[{qty:2,name:'mocha',milk_type:'whole',size:'small',price:2.5}], 'PLACED','order is in process');
```

but when I try to do the same using the DataStax Java driver for cassandra, I am not able to provide the user defined type as a list of objects. I could only come up with a string syntax, but obviously it is throwing the above error.

I have tried referring the datastax documentation, but apparently it is still a work in progress : http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/udts/

Here is my Java syntax:

```
 session.execute(insertorderPstmt.bind(UUID.randomUUID(),new BigDecimal("4"),"Santa Clara","[{qty:2,name:'mocha',milk_type:'whole',size:'small',price:2.5}]","PLACED","in process"));
```

and the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Invalid type for value 3, column is a list but class java.lang.String provided
```

Is there anyone who has been able to store custom type lists using java driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your insert query is not correct.**

If you use single quote then use it for everything, and separate all field with coma. If the field is string then enclose it with quote,

Use the below insert query :

```
INSERT INTO order (
     order_id,
     amount,
     location,
     items,
     status,
     message
 ) VALUES (
    e7ae5cf3-d358-4d99-b900-85902fda9bb0,
    5,
    'San Jose', 
     [
       {qty:2, name:'mocha', milk_type:'whole', size:'small', price:2.5}
     ],
     'PLACED',
     'order is in process'
);
```

Using Java Driver :

Though you are inserting User define Type(UDT) value, you have create a custom codec or insert value using `json` or `UDTValue`

Here is how you can insert value through UDTValue :

```
//First get your UserType from cluster object
UserType oderItemType = cluster.getMetadata()
        .getKeyspace(session.getLoggedKeyspace())
        .getUserType("order_items");

//Now you can create a UDTValue from your UserType order_items and set value 
UDTValue oderItem = oderItemType.newValue()
        .setInt("qty", 2)
        .setString("name", "mocha")
        .setString("milk_type", "whole")
        .setString("size", "small")
        .setDecimal("price", new BigDecimal(2.5));

// Though you define UDT of List Let's create a list and put the value
List<UDTValue> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(oderItem);
```

Now you can insert data like below :

```
//Let your prepared statment be like
PreparedStatement insertorderPstmt = session.prepare("insert into order(order_id,amount,location,items,status,message) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//Now you can bind the value and execute query
session.execute(insertorderPstmt.bind(UUID.randomUUID(), new BigDecimal("4"), "Santa Clara", orders, "PLACED", "in process"));
```

Comment: noted, and I can already insert using CQLSH but I am not able to insert using JAVA driver